# Find lowest value between 4 columns values from MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

tabl_priceList:

```
+--------+------+------+------+-------
| ProductID| price1 | price2 | price3 |
+--------+--------+------+------+------
|   10001 |   30    |  56    |   23   |
|   10002 |   650   | 560    |  675   |
|   10003 |   57    |  50    |  60    |
|   10004 |  300    | 305    |  3009  |
+--------+------+------+------+-------
```

I need to find out minimum column value for each row.

its look like.

```
-----+------+------+---
| ProductID| smallest | 
+--------+--------+-----
|   10001 |    23     | 
|   10002 |    560    | 
|   10003 |    50     | 
|   10004 |    300    | 
+--------+------+------
```

Please help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 7):

just use `LEAST()`

```
SELECT ProductID, LEAST(price1, price2, price3) smallest
FROM   tabl_priceList
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3930d/2)
- [MySQL LEAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least)

OUTPUT

```
╔═══════════╦══════════╗
║ PRODUCTID ║ SMALLEST ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╣
║     10001 ║       23 ║
║     10002 ║      560 ║
║     10003 ║       50 ║
║     10004 ║      300 ║
╚═══════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: Good. Didn't know about `LEAST()`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can also use `CASE` statement for the same:

```
SELECT
ProductID
, CASE WHEN price1 <= price2 and price1 <= price3 THEN Price1
       WHEN price2 <= price1 and price2 <= price3 THEN Price2
       ELSE price3 END AS smallest
FROM tabl_priceList;
```

Output:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════╗
║ PRODUCTID ║ SMALLEST ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╣
║     10001 ║       23 ║
║     10002 ║      560 ║
║     10003 ║       50 ║
║     10004 ║      300 ║
╚═══════════╩══════════╝
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3930d/1)

Comment: nice alternative but becomes complex if you have more than 3 prices to compare.